# Do these cut marks in the Batman Beyond episode "April Moon" have any meaning?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, batman-beyond

I was watching Batman Beyond episode ["April Moon"](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/April_Moon) and I saw this symbol when one of the characters cuts through the door.

[image: saw marks]

Is it supposed to be a Japanese symbol or character meaning something? Or is it just random? I thought it might be an Easter egg for fans to find.

Comment: A friend taking Japanese classes says it's neither hiragana nor katakana. She doesn't know about kanji.

Comment: @Jenayah - I maybe reading too much into it. :D.

Comment: It looks a little like the kanji for big. But not a lot

Comment: @Jenayah I can corroborate

Comment: @CorvoAttano - So it's most likely just a random lines made by the animators?

Comment: Was the door then kicked through? Perhaps it's just some quick cuts to make it easier to get through?

Comment: @Longshanks - Yes, because of the cuts they were able to break the door down in pieces. I thought it may have been an easter egg or have some meaning. They could have cut the door in 3 pieces rather than those awkward cuts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think so.

It's neither a [hiragana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana) nor a [katakana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana) nor one of the [Kanji with three strokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_kanji_by_stroke_count#Three_Strokes), even when flipped (since saw-wrists baddie cut the door from the outside).

Furthermore, considering the episode's context (Batman is about to ask Corso more questions, the tension rises up), it's not too far-fetched to think there isn't much more meaning than the bad guy needing to kick that door fast. And it kind of works, as the horizontal cut enables saw-wrists baddie to punch the upper part of the door, then thrust his whole body into smashing the lower part.

As far as I can see, the gang doesn't have a custom symbol, so it's probably not that either.

Comment: Chinese has 50,000 Hanzi (the Chinese word for kanji). Might be one of those (very low chance.)

Comment: nope, that does not resemble any chinese characters